# Unable to Upload An Image File Onto The FTP Server in php

Tags: php, jquery

```
$ftp=ftp_connect(“ftp.mywebsite.com”);
$login_result=ftp_login($ftp, “admin”, “adminpassword”);
$file = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
if(ftp_fput($ftp, $file,$fp, FTP_BINARY))
{   echo "success"; } 
else {  echo "error"; }
ftp_close($ftp);
fclose($fp);
```

I have made this script the php.net site and all i need now is to figure out how to get the users file to the ftp server not the one on my server. I was thinking I might need to upload their file to mine then from there to the ftp server any way here the code

Comment: Please describe the symptoms. Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I got error when I run on FTP server. I can't upload image.Actually, I like to save image in FTP Server's folder after I choose from upload file. It's ok running in my local server and can save image in the table

Comment: What was the exact error message?

Comment: bz I can't upload image file inside the FTP folder. then, I have condition, if it isn't return "success", the image won't display properly and show error message. If I could upload image to the Upload folder in the FTP site, I would be success.

Comment: $uploaddir = 'uploads/'; 
$file =$uploaddir.basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name']);
(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], $file)
I try to use move_uploaded_file function but it didn't work out in FTP

Comment: Watch out, you seem to have a case of the curlies.  Please check that your actual source file does not use curly quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
```

That's just the name of the file as it was provided by the client. Once uploaded, PHP stores it in a temporary file with a random name, which you access via the `['tmp_name']` attribute of the $_FILES array.

If you'd checked if the fopen() had succeeded (which it didn't), you'd have solved yourself this debugging problem:

```
$file = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb') or die("Unable to open $file for reading");
if (ftp_fput(...)) {
  etc...
}
```

Comment: I like to display image and save image in the table after I choose the image.then, I use php and jquery. I am not sure that I am in wrong logic saving image in FTP. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: after I upload the image, if error, I could see what image name.

Comment: DId you check if the file was sent to the webserver properly in the first place? `if ($_FILES['upload_file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { die("Upload failed"); }` is the basic method to test with.

Comment: if(response==="success"){    $('#files').html('<img src="uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />').addClass('success');$('#userphoto').hide();
} else{ $('#files').text(file).addClass('error');   }
this code checking in jquery file. I wonder that I could run in my local server. If I have "success", I could show image in my page immediatly and save in the table. Please help me out, I have tried 2 days ready. My brain is going to blow out.

Comment: new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
   action: 'uploadfile.php',
   name: 'uploadfile',
   onSubmit: function(file, ext){
     if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 
              
     status.text('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');
     return false;
    }
I have checked the image file opening properly.

Comment: Why are you ftping the file anyways? Wouldn't it be easier to just POST the file to that other server directly?

Comment: before upload image file, I have to show image file from table. then, if the user like to change their photo, they could do easily and once they choose it will be change in their photo in web page and save to the table. I don't get what you mean that just POST the file to that other server directly

Comment: Warning: fopen[function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in FTP_Testing.php on line 18
After I run it I have this error